# XMLHttpRequest - a problem with event.loaded and event.total values

Tags: javascript, ajax, event-handling, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

I use XMLHttpRequest for file upload and in the browser I've a progress bar that show, how big part of image is already uploaded.

```
  xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', onprogressHandler, false);

  function onprogressHandler(event) {    
    resp.innerHTML = event.loaded +' and '+ event.total;

    var percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
    var calc_display = document.getElementById('calc');
    calc_display.innerHTML = percent;
  };
```

If I choose an image for upload and send a form, so I see always the same values of `event.loaded` and `event.total`.
I think the value `event.total` is the size of file.

I am a newbie so I haven't so much of experience, but how is possible I have always the same  values? (usually about 2.700.000 kB)

Where could be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [progress event spec](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/progress/#firing-events-using-the-progressevent-interface-for-http) mentions that a progress event can also have a boolean-valued `.lengthComputable` attribute.  If that attribute is false on a progress event, I would expect the values of `event.loaded` and `event.total` to not reflect the progress of the upload.

The specification says that `.lengthComputable` will be true and `.total` will reflect the length of the file if the `Content-Length` header of the XMLHttpRequest is set.  It turns out that [XMLHttpRequest will not allow setting `Content-Length`](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/#the-setrequestheader-method)-- search for `Content-Length` just below that anchor.  Presumably they do this because a script might miscalculate the length of the data it is sending and the user agent is far less likely to do so.

Look at the requests that your server is receiving.  Do they have a `Content-Length` header?

Comment: Hi ellisbben, yes. If I will send the form and see to the console, so I see there `Content-Length 2730561
X-File-Name SDC10289-1.JPG
Content-Type image/jpeg` and the `Content-Length` I have set as `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", file.size);`. What could be again wrong?

Comment: First, either use `console.log(percent);` or `calc_display.innerHTML += percent + "<br/>";` so that you can be sure that the value isn't changing.  Try separately logging and looking at the values of `event.lengthComputable`, `event.loaded`, and `event.total`, and your `percent` value, e.g., with `console.log([percent, event.lengthComputable, event.loaded, event.total]);`; let me know what you find.

Comment: Ok, so I did everything what you wrote me. First - the value is still the same (still "100"). I tried to log `percent` and `events` and I got: `[52, true, 1408556, 2684842]` and `[100, true, 2684842, 2684842]`. In firebug I see `POST /photos/upload 200 OK 2778ms`, but on my page I see only the number 100 (%)

Comment: I now think your code runs fine and I stupidly ignored the simple explanation.  Did you try `calc_display.innerHTML += percent + "<br/>";` instead of `calc_display.innerHTML = percent;`?  That should show you as many values of percent on your page as you see in the console.

Comment: Yes, I did it and I got this: `[23, true, 638716, 2772369]
[65, true, 1800680, 2772369]
[100, true, 2772369, 2772369]` (23% - 65% - 100%). But I see the value  **100%** and then the upload is finished in the next 2-3 seconds... That not looks very nice.

Comment: There is, in theory, a separate event type (`'load'`) which will fire when the upload is completely finished; you could force the percentage to never go higher than 95% on a `'progress'` event and then set it to 100% on a `'load'` event.  Disclaimer: I don't know about browser support for these event types.

Comment: I tried to check the `'load'` event, but unfortunately I don't know why, it wasn't possible to get the time of duration of upload. So now, my project is co close to deadline, so I have to percent-loader replace with "Loading" text with some animation and then I have to figure out, why `event.loaded` and `event.total` contains bad values... In any case, thank you so much for your help, ellisbben.

Answer (score 0):

Values might be same if your uploaded video/image size is small. You can check by uploading video of size more than 70MB and check your loaded and total values, it should give you different values in total and loaded

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).